# How to bend this object

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I’m trying to make this environment but I’m actually having trouble with this curve. I know I can manually do it but I feel like it won’t look natural and smooth. I saw tutorials using the simple deform but that applies to the whole object while the one in the photo is more like a L shape.[image: the part circled with red]

Comment: Maybe add this object in your question (upload a blend file)? Considering the style in the picture, consider doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can begin with a perpendicular plane:

[image]

Bevel the angle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the faces along the normals:

[image]

[image]

Scale if necessary, select the edges and bevel again to round the angles:

[image]

[image]